# Can't run rspec correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

rspec version: 3.5
rails version: 5.2

Controller:

```
def show
  # Remove all source.
end
```

Test controller:

```
describe 'GET #show' do
  it 'returns not found' do
    get :show, params: {id: post}
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:not_found)
  end
end
```

This test case will test a 404 status, but got 500 internal server error:

```
expected the response to have status code :not_found (404) but it was :internal_server_error (500)
```

When ran the test with `--backtrace`:

```
$ rspec spec/controller/posts_controller_spec.rb --backtrace
```

Can found this line got error:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(:not_found)
   expected the response to have status code :not_found (404) but it was :internal_server_error (500)
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-support-3.7.1/lib/rspec/support.rb:97:in `block in <module:Support>'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-support-3.7.1/lib/rspec/support.rb:106:in `notify_failure'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.7.0/lib/rspec/expectations/fail_with.rb:35:in `fail_with'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.7.0/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:40:in `handle_failure'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.7.0/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:50:in `block in handle_matcher'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.7.0/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:27:in `with_matcher'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.7.0/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:48:in `handle_matcher'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/given_core-3.8.0/lib/given/rspec/monkey.rb:21:in `handle_matcher'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.7.0/lib/rspec/expectations/expectation_target.rb:65:in `to'
 # ./spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:254:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:254:in `block in run'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:500:in `block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `block in with_around_example_hooks'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:466:in `block in run'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:606:in `block in run_around_example_hooks_for'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:342:in `call'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.7.2/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:191:in `block (2 levels) in <module:ControllerExampleGroup>'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:375:in `execute_with'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:608:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:342:in `call'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.7.2/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:127:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:375:in `execute_with'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:608:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:342:in `call'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:609:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:466:in `run'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `with_around_example_hooks'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:500:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:251:in `run'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:628:in `block in run_examples'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:624:in `map'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:624:in `run_examples'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `run'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:591:in `block in run'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:591:in `map'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:591:in `run'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:591:in `block in run'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:591:in `map'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:591:in `run'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `map'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1926:in `with_suite_hooks'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `block in run_specs'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:79:in `report'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `run_specs'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:87:in `run'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
 # /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

So is it the version conflict between `rspec-rails` and `rails`?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're asking. Your spec fails because your controller returns a different error (500) than what you're expecting (404). Do you have a reason to think the problem is not somewhere in your controller implementation, but in your rspec setup instead?

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Controller has no problem. If write nothing on that method, also return 500 error.

Comment: I'm not really sure what that means to be honest, but regardless: the problem is that your question doesn't contain a [mcve] - it's not possible for others to try and reproduce your issue. That makes it hard to diagnose and formulate an answer.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra I want to know why it got `internal_server_error (500)` error. I don't know the reason now.

Comment: Put another way: show your controller code. Show why you expect it to return a 404, and demonstrate why it returning a 500 is _not_ a problem in your controller. Simply you telling us "it's not the controller" is not helpful in figuring this out I'm afraid.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra I added a sample controller. The problem really not is the controller logic. All the controllers got failed in the whole project.

Comment: Strange. But the backtrace showing the `rspec/support` line is really not an indication that your rspec setup is wrong btw, that just shows where the rspec code that notifies you about a failing test lives.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Sorry, I added full trace.

Comment: that full trace still looks normal to me, and is still only a trace of the call to _report_ the test failure. AFAICT it's not tracing the _cause_ of the test failure. This is getting a bit beyond what we can do in comments, but I would suggest that you use a debugger like `byebug` or `pry` to try and see what's going on - see if the spec even hits your controller method, or if it fails before that.

Comment: Did you define a view for this model? Otherwise it's logical you get a 500 error instead of 404.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Thank you. I will do that later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code

```
def show
  # Remove all source.
end
```

There is no render or redirect code in this method, So it will try to render the implicit view show.html.erb. But if you don't have that view defined, it will return 500(internal server error)

If you just want to show not found, then give

```
def show
  head :not_found
end
```